# Use xarray to get sums in time for each point in a grid

Tags: python-xarray

I have a gridded dataset with three dimensions: lat, lon, and time.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (lat: 185, lon: 155, time: 8760)
Coordinates:
  * lon          (lon) float64 -76.98 -76.92 -76.86 -76.8 -76.74 ...
  * lat          (lat) float64 33.55 33.6 33.66 33.71 33.76 33.82 ...
  * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 2010-01-01 2010-01 01T01:00:00.028800 ...
Data variables:
    u            (time, lat, lon) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    v            (time, lat, lon) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    u_err        (time, lat, lon) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    v_err        (time, lat, lon) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
```

I'd like to get a mean of all u and v through time, which I can do by the following:

```
ds_seasonal = ds.groupby('time.season').mean('time')
```

However, I only want to get the mean of the dataset for each gridpoint where there is data present 50% of the time or more.

In MATLAB, I would put everything into a structured array and it would be as easy as `nans=sum(~isnan(u),3);`  which I would then compare to 4335 or 50% of the time dimension.

I'm just learning how to use xarray for computation. Is this possible with xarray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` is the way to mask values in xarray. You can use it to write a custom aggregation function with `groupby.apply()`, e.g.,

```
def custom_mean(ds):
    missing_frac = result.isnull().mean('time')
    return result.mean('time').where(missing_frac < 0.5)

result = ds.groupby('time.season').apply(custom_mean)
```